# How are fonts sized when specifying "px" in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to pin down exactly what `px` means to font-size in terms of allocated space on the page, and the results I'm getting don't match my expectations.

I was under the impression that using pixels in conjunction with `font-size` meant that the vertical space taken up by the typography would match the value specified.  For example, if I specified `font-size: 16px`, a line of text with that rule applied would have a height of `16px`.  Please note that I was not expecting the *actual glyph* to be `16px` in height, but that the browser would allocate `16px` to display the glyphs.

Here's some code to use as a reference so I can explain what I expected to see vs. what I'm actually seeing:

```css
.style-it {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="style-it">
  <div>
    CSS
  </div>
  <div>
    IS
  </div>
  <div>
    AWESOME
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

I have a static height of `500px` set on my `style-it div`, which has a `5px border` and `20px padding`.  Therefore, the content of my `div` has a height of `450px`.  With my previous understanding of `font-size` and `px`, I would expect three lines of text at a `font-size` of `150px` to fill that `450px` of content perfectly, but that isn't the case.

I've placed each line of text into their own `div` so we can clearly see that each line is slightly larger (`173px` in Chrome) than my `150px` specification.

So, what's going on here?  Is it that the glyphs themselves actually are `150px` in height and the "box" around them adjusts arbitrarily based on some internal browser rule?

Is there a way that I would be able to know for sure that "I have container that is `Xpx` tall and I can fit Y lines of text perfectly in there by setting their `font-size` to `Zpx`"?

Just an interesting problem that I came across that I couldn't find a good answer to.  I don't know if it's terribly useful in the real world, but I was interested to see if anyone could answer nonetheless.

**EDIT:** I should have been a little clearer on what I was asking.  I'm not having trouble figuring out how to fit the text inside the div, but rather interested in why, as the duplicate linked article states, the `font-size` value is not the same size as the `em-square`.  In other words, why is specifying a `line-height` of `1em` even necessary in a situation like this?

For anyone who comes across this, the linked question has a great article that is just the sort of thing I was looking for: http://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align#lets-talk-about-font-size-first

Comment: I recommend accepting @Michal's answer, even though it is a little bit of a frame challenge (doesn't answer the exact question asked). You have an XY problem, I suspect. You really just want to fit N lines into a container perfectly, but you think that the best way to do that is by calculating pixels, however modifying `line-height` seems (to me) to be the best solution, since knowing how different browsers render font may be untenable.

Comment: @ksav If I am correct in thinking that the author is dealing with an XY problem, then the actual problem they want solved is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: True. I've just read @Michal's answer and it seems to explain what the op is *most likely* trying to figure out.

Comment: must i say that border isnt conssidered part of width, since i remember making triangles using width 0 and setting pixel widths to borders

therefore it would be 500-40 not 500-40-10. which seem to be exactely the extra pixels that seem to pop out with ur css plus the line height is also an interseting concept u have to consider too

Answer (score 2):

Your line is not exactly `150px` in height because `line-height` and `text-size` are two different things.
Use the CSS property `line-height` and set it to `1em` (which means that the line height will be the same size as the text size), and your content will be exactly `450px` in height.

```css
.style-it {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin: auto; 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 500px; 
    border: 5px solid black; 
    padding: 20px; 
    font-size: 150px;
    line-height: 1em; /* add this line */
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
<html>
 <div class="style-it">
  <div>
   CSS
  </div>
  <div>
   IS
  </div>
  <div>
   AWESOME
  </div>
 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty sure that if left unspecified, the browser has its own defaults for line-height that it will use to fit the font-size with some extra spacing. Only way to make sure that your container is exactly the same height as your font-size is to specify the line-height

Comment: Good answer, if a little bit of a frame challenge. I suspect that the original question is an XY problem: they really want to be able to fit N lines into region, they think that the best way to do that is to calculate this by pixels, when really the best way is to adjust the line-height property.

Comment: @GregSchmit The question isn't looking for the "best way" to accomplish the task, only asking why that particular method isn't a viable solution when it would appear at a distance to be.

Comment: @Mr-Programs 150 is correct since the border width (10px) is included in the height of the element thanks to the box-sizing property

Comment: @TylerBurki Then congrats: you asked a duplicate question which has already been answered. I was being charitable in assuming that your actual problem wasn't solved by that duplicate; this answer is how you go about getting text to fit neatly into containers the way you described.

Comment: @GregSchmit Apologies, no harm intended, just wanted to clarify the question

Comment: @TylerBurki Not a problem! Looking back, my response now appears rude, but it wasn't intended to be.